# Golang - unable to parse JSON

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I've started learning GO, and i have encountered this issue.
I have this code

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "encoding/json"
)


func main(){
  type Weather struct {
    name string
    cod float64
    dt float64
    id float64
  }

  var rawWeather = []byte(`{"name":"London","cod":200,"dt":1407100800,"id":2643743}`)
  var w Weather
  err := json.Unmarshal(rawWeather, &w)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("%s : while parsing json", err)
  }
  log.Printf("%+v\n",w)
}
```

when i run it, it shows this

```
[nap@rhel projects]$ go run euler.go 
{name: cod:0 dt:0 id:0}
```

So, the JSON is not parsed into the weather struct.

Any ideas, why do this happens like this?

Comment: Make the struct fields as exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By quessing, i found, that this code works:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "encoding/json"
//  "net/html"
)


func main(){
  type Weather struct {
    Name string
    Cod float64
    Dt float64
    Id float64
  }

  var rawWeather = []byte(`[{"name":"London","cod":200,"dt":1407100800,"id":2643743}]`)
  var w []Weather
  err := json.Unmarshal(rawWeather, &w)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Some error", err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n",w)
}
```

So, the struct field names have to be Capitalized to work properly!

Comment: Capitalizing its properties means give them a "public visibility" in an instance scope, I suppose... Am I wrong or sounds weird a struct defined inside the main function?

Comment: @ilpaijin please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380268/where-to-declare-structures-inside-main-or-outside-main/31383984

Answer (score 7):

You need to capitalise your struct fields. E.g:

```
Name string
Cod  float64
// etc..
```

This is because they are not visible to the `json` package when attempting to unmarshal.

Playground link: http://play.golang.org/p/cOJD4itfIS

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Weather` does not export any fields. This;

```
type Weather struct {
   name string
   cod float64
   dt float64
   id float64
}
```

Needs to be;

```
type Weather struct {
   Name string
   Cod float64
   Dt float64
   Id float64
}
```

If a field is not exported then the json package will not be able to access it. You can find more information about it here http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go but the short version is;

" The json package only accesses the exported fields of struct types (those that begin with an uppercase letter). Therefore only the the exported fields of a struct will be present in the JSON output."