# where to declare structures, inside main() or outside main()?

Tags: c, struct

**Case 1:** structure declared outside `main()` working fine

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct prod
{
    int price,usold;
};
int main()
{
    struct prod *p,a;

    int billamt(struct prod *);
    int bill;
    printf("enter the values \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&p->price,&p->usold);
    bill=billamt(p);
    printf("bill=%d",bill);
    getch();
}
int billamt(struct prod *i)
{
    int b;
    b=(i->price*i->usold);
    return b;
}
```

**Case 2:** declared inside `main()` giving error

> [Error] type 'main()::prod' with no linkage used to declare function 'int billamt(main()::prod*)' with linkage [-fpermissive]*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    struct prod
{
    int price,usold;
};


    struct prod *p,a;

    int billamt(struct prod *);
    int bill;
    printf("enter the values \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&p->price,&p->usold);
    bill=billamt(p);
    printf("bill=%d",bill);
    getch();
}
int billamt(struct prod *i)
{
    int b;
    b=(i->price*i->usold);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: If option #1 works fine but option #2 gives an error saying that it cannot be done... I'd say go with option #1!

Answer (score 20):

> *where to declare structures, inside `main()` or outside `main()`?*

1. First thing, I think you meant "define", not "declare".
2. Second, there is no *rule* as such, You can define wherever you want. It is all about the *scope* of the definition.

   - If you define the structure inside `main()`, the scope is limited to `main()` only. Any other function cannot see that definition and hence, cannot make use of that structure definition.
   - If you define the structure in a global scope, (i.e., outside `main()` or any other function, for that matter), that definition is available globally and all the functions can *see* and make use of the structure definition.

Answer (score 4):

It have to do about *scoping*, when you define the structure inside the `main` function then it's only defined in the scope of the `main` function, so the `billamt` function can't know about it.

Answer (score 3):

Structure are a like array only the main difference in Array can hold only same type of values but a structure can have different types of values so if you need to implement structure globally(by globally i mean it can be used in any other function too) define it outside the main and if you want to use your structure only in the main function define it inside it.
Happy Coding :-)