# How to pass local structures to functions?

Tags: c, scope, sdl, pass-by-reference, sdl-2

The following link says that structs defined in `main` don't have the scope to be called by functions because they are local so you should define your structs globally. However with variables, it's preferred to declare variables locally and pass to functions with pointers instead of declaring global variables.

Is there a way in pure C using pointers etc to pass a struct defined in main to a function? If you don't mind, please use the example program to demonstrate the method. Thanks.

[where to declare structures, inside main() or outside main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380268/where-to-declare-structures-inside-main-or-outside-main)

This code works but is not what I want. I want to define the structure within `main`. Is this possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

void function();

struct hexColour
    {
        Uint32 red;
    }hc;

int main(void)
{
    hc.red = 0xFFFF0000;
    function(hc);
    return 0;
}

void function(struct hexColour hc)
{
    printf("red is %x\n", hc.red);
}
```

What I want is:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct hexColour
    {
        Uint32 red;
    }hc;
    hc.red = 0xFFFF0000;
    function(hc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can pass structs the same way as anything else. The linked answer was read by you in a misleading way.

Comment: Looking at that question (and the answers) one can see how much lower SO standards were in 2015 :)

Comment: To clarify, do you mean you want to have `int main(void) { struct hexColour { ... }; struct hexColour hc; ...; function(hc); }` and then be able to access the member of the structure in the function `function` (like you do in it now)? Or do you mean that you want to *emulate pass by reference* and define the structure itself in the global scope, and then in `function` you want to *modify* the members of a structure *instance* defined in the `main` function? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you really want to do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I have to define `struct hexColour` outside `main` like I've shown in the question, then so be it. But I did mean the first thing that you put in your comment. I ideally want everything in main except the function prototype and function definition.

Comment: You confuse scope and storage duration, aka lifetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should really use proper prototypes that matched the function definitions.

Secondly, your example *do* pass a structure into the local variable `hc` in the function.

When `function` is running there are two distinct and separate structures in memory: The one in the `main` function, and the local in the `function` function.

---

To cover my bases, here are two answers for two other question that maybe is asked:

1. You want to define the structure itself inside the `main` function, and then be able to use it in other functions.

   Something like

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       struct hexColor
       {
           uint32_t white;
           // Other members omitted
       };

       struct hexColour hc;
       hc.white = 0xff;

       func(hc);  // Assume declaration exist
   }

   void func(struct hexColour my_colour)
   {
       printf("White is %u\n", my_colour.white);
   }
   ```

   This is *not* possible. The structure `hexColour` is defined inside the `main` function only. No other function can use that structure. It doesn't matter if you pass a pointer or not, the structure `hexColour` still will only exist inside the `main` function only.
2. Emulate pass-by-reference by passing a pointer to a structure object. Like

   ```
   struct hexColor
   {
       uint32_t white;
       // Other members omitted
   };

   int main(void)
   {
       struct hexColour hc;
       hc.white = 0xff;

       // Assume declaration of function exists
       func(&hc);  // Emulate pass-by-reference by passing a pointer to a variable
   }

   void func(struct hexColour *colourPointer)
   {
       colourPointer->white = 0x00;
   }
   ```

   This *is* possible, because then the structure `hexColour` exists outside the `main` function, in the global scope. All functions declared and defined after the structure definition may use the structure and its members.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with structs so maybe I'm making a mistake somewhere but the way shown above is the only way I can get that program working. When I add `struct hexColour` to the parameter list of the prototype I get a bunch of warnings and errors such as "conflicting types for 'function'" and "argument type 'struct hexColour' is incomplete". That's why I left the parameter list blank in the prototype.

Comment: @User.Flynn Basically copy the first line (`void function(struct hexColour hc)`) and put a semi-colon after it. And make sure you define the structure before!

Comment: @User.Flynn Then you can't use the structure outside of the `main` function. And I also start to wonder what your *real* problem is? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and finally learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That was my question though XD

Comment: A variable can be declared in main and used via pointers in functions. So is there a way to define a struct in main and use it in functions?

Comment: @User.Flynn For that question the answer is no. The structure is defined in the *scope* of the `main` function. Any other function will be out of scope for the structure definition. If you want a structure to be available to other function, it needs to be defined to it's in scope for all functions that use it.

Comment: You can pass a pointer as a a parameter. You can pass the struct itself as parameter. As I said - as any other variable. It's just that it is recommended to use pointers as `struct`s are typically large and it is a bit expensive to copy and pass it on stack (or wherever the ABI suggests)

Comment: @User.Flynn However, you can pass a pointer to an instance of the structure to any function accepting the generic pointer `void *` as argument. The function can't do anything with the structure though, since they don't have the definition, and therefore the members of the structure will be unknown.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems there is a misunderstanding here - defining structure type (which have to be in global scope so all function can see it) vs. declaring variable of said struct type (which is more than ok to be local to functions).

Comment: That was it. You've explained that what I wanted is not possible. Sorry for the big confusion, I'm not that clear on the correct terminology so my question wasn't precise enough. Thanks for taking the time to work with me and answer the question though. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass by value a copy is made (expensive, modifications are not reflected outside). If you want to pass a pointer to a `struct` just go with, **but this doesn't mean you are passing a `struct` by reference (C doesn't have references), you are passing a pointer to a `struct` by value instead**.

```
void function(struct hexColour* hc) {
  printf("red is %x", hc->red);
}

int main() {
  ...
  functon(&hc);
  ...
}
```

See:

- Signature of the function changes from `struct hexColor` to `struct hexColor*` so that you are passing a pointer (by value)
- To access field of the `struct` when dealing with pointers you use `->` instead that `.`
- You need to take the address to the struct when invoking the function, `function(hc)` becomes `function(&hc)`

Now since you are passing the address the the struct any modification is done to the real value.

Comment: When I follow the code you've written, I get an error saying `incomplete definition of type 'struct hexColour'` and a warning saying `declaration of 'struct hexColour' will not be visible outside of this function`. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have understood your linked question and its answers incompletely.  You write,

> The following link says that structs defined in main don't have the
>   scope to be called by functions because they are local so you should
>   define your structs globally.

The ambiguity here is between struct *types*, such as your `struct hexColour`, and *objects* having those types, such as your `hc`.  Both struct types and struct objects should be declared so that they are in scope at all the places where they are needed, but that plays out differently for these two different kinds of entities and in various different situations.

> However with variables, it's preferred to declare variables locally
>   and pass by reference instead of declaring global variables.

It is usually best to use block-scope variables instead of file-scope variables, yes, but C has only pass by value, not pass by reference.  There are plenty of circumstances where it is advantageous to pass pointers (by value) instead of the objects to which they point, and this is close to pass by reference, but there is certainly no rule or general practice that passing pointers is universally better than passing the objects to which they point.

> Is there
>   a way in pure C using pointers etc to pass a local struct to a
>   function?

Both the caller and the callee have to agree about the type of each argument, and there are many ways to achieve this.  But there are some conventions that have grown up along with C for how to approach problems such as these in an effective way.  Large among them is this:

- Any function and any non-builtin type that is to be used in multiple translation units should be declared in a header file, and that header included in every translation unit that needs it.

That's a generalization of the rule you couched in terms of "global" definitions.  Example:

**colour.h**

```
#ifndef COLOUR_H
#define COLOUR_H

struct hexColour {
    Uint32 white;
    Uint32 black;
    Uint32 red;
    Uint32 pink;
    Uint32 grey;
}; // Note that only the type is declared here, not any objects

void function(struct hexColour hc);

#endif
```

Note that the declaration of type `struct hexColour` appears before the declaration of function `function` that has a parameter of that type.
You can then use those types and functions with appropriate locality, for example:

**main.c**:

```
#include "colour.h"

int main(void) {
    struct hexColour hc = {
        .white = 0xFFFFFFFF, .black = 0xFF000000, .red = 0xFFFF0000,
        .pink = 0xFFFF9999,  .grey = 0xFFA0A0A0 };

    function(hc);
    return 0;
}

void function(struct hexColour hc) {
    printf("red is %x\n", hc.red);
}
```

Note that the declaration of `function` that forms part of its definition here matches the declaration in the header.  That definition `function()` could as easily be defined in a different source file, instead, as long as the caller has the header file to tell it how that function is declared.  You can `#include` coulour.h into as many different source files as needed.

Do note, however, that in this case, the struct is passed by value.  That's well-defined and perfectly acceptable, but inasmuch as the function receives only a copy, it cannot effect changes to the caller's original copy.  If you wanted the function to be able to do that, then you would need to pass a pointer to the struct (by value) instead of the struct itself:

```
void function(struct hexColour *hc) {
    // ...
}

int main(void) {
    // ...
    function(&hc);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a locally-defined struct and pass it to another function:

```
void f1(struct s);

int main()
{
    struct s s1;
    f1(s1);
}
```

You can take a locally-defined struct and pass a pointer to it to another function:

```
void f2(struct s *);

int main()
{
    struct s s2;
    f2(&s2);
}
```

You can return a locally-defined struct:

```
struct s f3()
{
    struct s ret;
    /* ... */
    return ret;
}
```

You can *not* return a *pointer* to a locally-defined struct:

```
struct s *f4()
{
    struct s ret;
    /* ... */
    return &ret;     /* WRONG */
}
```

If you declare a struct within a function, it is not a global variable, so you can not refer to it in another function to which you did not pass the structure or a pointer:

```
void f5();

int main()
{
    struct s s1;
    f5();
}

void f5()
{
    int x = s1.field;    /* WRONG */
}
```

Finally, if you declare the struct type itself inside a function, you end up with a struct which you can't properly refer to elsewhere:

```
void f1(struct s);

int main()
{
    struct s { int a, b; } s1;
    f1(s1);
}

void f1(struct s arg)    /* error: this struct s might not be the same as the previous one */
{
    int x = arg.b;       /* error: compiler might not know that struct s contains a and b */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the previous answers. Suggest you wrap your mind around the 'C' difference between a declaration and a definition. Note that earlier versions of 'C' would NOT allow passing a copy of a structure on the stack, only a pointer to a struct..